# Reducing lambda calculus term to normal form

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

This is for homework before anyone asks, I'm just looking for guidance.

**Here is the first question term:**

```
(λx.λy.x y)(λx.x y)
=(λx.λz.x z)(λx.x y)         α-renaming 
=(λz.(λx.x y)  z) 
=(λx.x y)
```

I would like to make sure I'm thinking of this correctly. The term on the right is the value placed into the parameter x, correct? Then every instance of x is replaced with the term on the right. I renamed y so there wasn't any confusion with the free y and the bounded y. Now the thing I don't understand is the second line starting with =. Does the rightmost z get passed as the parameter for variable z? Or does it get passed into x? Either way I think the answer is the same, but I'd like to know which is the correct method.

**Here is the second question term**

```
((λx.λy.x y)(λx.x))  y
=((λx.λz.x z)(λx.x))  y 
=(λz.(λx.x)z)  y 
=(λx.x)y 
=(λx.x)
```

Because of the parentheses, does the term (λx.x) get substituted for the parameter x? Or does y get substituted for x?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda calculus consists in a context-free grammar

```
E ::= v        Variable
   |  λ v. E   Abstraction
   |  E E      Application
```

where `v` ranges over variables, together with the beta- and eta-reduction rules

```
(λ x. B) E  ->  B   where every occurrence of x in B in substituted by E
  λ x. E x  ->  E   if x doesn't occur free in E
```

`a` is *free* in `λ b. b a`, but not in `λ a. λ b. b a`. An expression to which neither of the two reduction rules apply is in *normal form*.

Reduction of leftmost redexes is prioritized. *Applicative order* normalizes arguments before substitution, *normal order* does not.

Correct normal-order beta- and eta-normalization of the two expressions:

```
   (λ x. (λ y. x y)) (λ a. a b)
=  (λ x. x) (λ a. a b)            Eta-reduction
=  λ a. a b                       Beta-reduction

   ((λ x. (λ y. x y)) (λ a. a)) f
=  ((λ x. x) (λ a. a)) f
=  (λ a. a) f
=  f
```